# MongoDB how to update a count field with the number of elements that are in an array on the document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to update a field that I have on my `Post` model. The Post model looks like the following:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
  }
  likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  upvotes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
})
```

I have a database of `posts` that I would like to `update` by counting their `likes` (stored ID's) and `update` the `upvotes` to the number of likes in the document. Is there a way to do this? I can use the `Mongo shell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mongo version 4.2+ you can use [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to do this, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      upvotes: {
        $size: "$likes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SzPmwVyjCkp)

For lesser Mongo versions you'll have to read each document into memory, and execute an update for it.